# Unable to generate application cryptogram (ac) - VISA Contactless transaction

Tags: apdu, emv, contactless-smartcard

I'm trying to simulate a visa contactless transaction.

The CDOL1 data is 9F02069F03069F1A0295055F2A029A039C019F3704, which translates to:

- "9F02" + "06";
- "9F03" + "06";
- "9F1A" + "02";
- "95"   + "05";
- "5F2A" + "02";
- "9A"   + "03";
- "9C"   + "01";
- "9F37" + "04";

I created the GENERATE APPLICATION CRYPTOGRAM command following these specifications:

- "80" (cla)
- "AE" (ins)
- "80" (p1)
- "00" (p2)
- "1D" (lc)
- "000000000000" + "000000000000" + "----" + "0000000000" + "----" + "230511" + "01" + "50D49E9C" (data)
- "00" (le)

but I'm getting 6A 81, which means "Function not supported", according to [this page](https://www.eftlab.com/knowledge-base/complete-list-of-apdu-responses).

The data with "----" is 4 characters lenght and omitted in the question.

Anyone can help me? Thanks!

Comment: This is not an attempt to make a nasty comment, but have you tried to read the specs? What are you doing it for and do you want to achieve?

Comment: This is not answerable, as we don't see any context, such as which APDU's have been issued before this particular APDU. You may not have selected an application or something similar.